# PHP array index how to unset it

Tags: php

I have example those values:

```
$waiting['s9d8393838333'][] = array("client_id" => "2039833");
$waiting['s9d8393838333'][] = array("client_id" => "1039833");
```

How can i delete a client_id from the array? ex if i will delete client_id => 2039833 ?

```
foreach ( $waiting as $e => $array):
    if ( $array['client_id'] == $clientID):
         //Here i should delete that index ???
    endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Do you want to delete `array("client_id" => 2039833")` or `"client_id" => 2039833` ?

Comment: can you show us the desired output of `$waiting` ?

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/QcrzQh i want to delete the array where client_id is xxxxxx

Comment: @jesper http://codepad.viper-7.com/ut9UpS

Answer (score 2):

That's what [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) is for:

```
foreach ( $waiting['s9d8393838333'] as $key => $array ) {
    if ( $array['client_id'] == $clientID ) {
        unset( $waiting['s9d8393838333'][$key] );
        break;
    }
}
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/6dmr3N

Comment: Are you sure that would work? It doesn't make sence if it should.

Comment: @jesper - Check out the demo I posted.

Comment: As it is also the key of another array, you've to unset the key of the parent array to delete this field, and not simply unset it as you did in your demo, it's not the same case. I think the correct solution is the one given by Mic1780.

Comment: @C.Malet - The OP only said that they want to delete the `client_id` index from the `$array` array. They should clarify this.

Comment: @C.Malet Thanks for the reference. The reason I do it my way is because you are *searching* for the $clientID. the array is three deep so a double foreach loop + the key reference is needed to find the correct clientID.

Comment: Guys, it's not working, check following: http://codepad.viper-7.com/QcrzQh doesn't delete the client_id array ...

Comment: @jesper - Now that you've clarified that you want to completely delete the array, I've updated the answer and the link to the demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($waiting as $key => $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key2 => $val) {
        if ($val['client_id'] == $clientID) {
            unset($waiting[$key][$key2]);
        }//END IF
    }//END FOREACH LOOP
}//END FOREACH LOOP
```

If you want to "keep the logic" as a complaint of someone, use this:

```
foreach ($waiting as $key => $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key2 => $val) {
        if ($val['client_id'] == $clientID) {
            unset($waiting[$key][$key2]);
        endif;
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

With that you can change if you want more or less than just client_id

Working example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ut9UpS

Comment: how does it change the logic? it does exactly as asked. the difference is the end braces.

Comment: You're checking if the name of the key is `client_id`, not if the value is `$clientID`...

Comment: Not working. Check http://codepad.viper-7.com/j3mVfa ... it doesnt delete the array.

Comment: @Mic1780 There's a difference between *syntax* and *logic*. I wasn't concerned about the difference in syntax (i.e. end braces), but you weren't comparing the correct things in the original answer.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 I can understand that. The loop code in the question is wrong to start. so i fixed it and answered the question